# api authorization header r httr

Tags: r, swagger, tidyverse, httr

I am trying to access the Open Apparel Registry api using `httr`.

NB: It's free to sign up (need to login + get authentication code on profile page).
But you can see the swagger api docs here: https://openapparel.org/api/docs/#!/facilities/facilities_list

Here is how you authorize on web version:
[image]

```
oar_root_api <- "https://openapparel.org/api/facilities/"
oar_token <- XXX
oar_api_facilities_GET <- httr::GET(url = oar_root_api,
                                    add_headers(
                                                `Authorization` = oar_token),
                                    verbose()
                                    )
```

The code I receive back is `401` so something is wrong with my authorization, but I've tried so many ways. I can't figure out how to specify this correctly.

Comment: Have you asked the API vendor for support?

Comment: I sent a message to them, but thought it might be an easy fix and SO could help.

Comment: Anyways I'm fairly new to APIs, so what might be a good question to ask?

Comment: Rather than posting to the actual site, you might debug by posting a request from R to https://httpreq.com/ so you can see exactly what's being sent. And compare that to a version you send via `curl` from the example they list on the API test page. That should help you detect if there are any header/encoding issues that might be causing a problem.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. I tried this method, but I don't see anything obvious. Are you able to query this? Or what would be your `httr` query? It sounds like you might think I have written the code (somewhat) correctly on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to hear you've been having difficulties. This additional documentation may help: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZKCN84Eu9WDAXUokojOw7Dcg5TAJw0vKnVk7RPrTPZ0/edit?usp=sharing

We tend to find that users need to add the "Token" prefix (see page 3), which I appreciate isn't standard practice - this is something we intend to change!

Let us know how you get on.

- OAR

Answer (score 3):

The Open Apparel Registry (OAR) uses [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to provide API enpoints. The `TokenAuthentication` class requires that the `Authorization` header value have a "Token " prefix. From the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

> For clients to authenticate, the token key should be included in the Authorization HTTP header. The key should be prefixed by the string literal "Token", with whitespace separating the two strings. For example:
>
> ```
> Authorization: Token 9944b09.....
> ```

I am not familiar with R, but I searched for string concatenation and it looks like the `paste` function will build the header value that you need.

```
oar_root_api <- "https://openapparel.org/api/facilities/"
oar_token <- XXX
oar_api_facilities_GET <- httr::GET(url = oar_root_api,
                                    add_headers(
                                                `Authorization` = paste("Token ", oar_token)),
                                    verbose()
                                    )
```